# Excel 2013 VBA Creating Buttons for a New Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Long time user, first time poster!

I work at a Campus Food Shelf and I've recently become very involved in streamlining their reporting and data entry. The task I'm currently preforming is making a program that would create a uniformed sheet 1, so that the reporting programs I've built thus far can be easily exported to new workbooks, long after I graduate. I'm familiar (but by no means an expert) with C/C++, Python, and most recently VBA.

I'm running into an error when creating buttons for Sheet 1. The error is: "Identifier under cursor is not recognized". The result I'm looking for with this code is to create 5 separate buttons linked to 5 separate Sub programs that have already been defined. I would like to place them at specific places with specific sizes. The code in question is:

```
Sub DONOTUSEbuttonMaker()
Dim Report1, Report2, Report3, Unique, NewWork As Object

Dim Targeter As Range
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 5
  Select Case i:
    Case 1:
        Set Targeter = Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(3, 7), Cells(3, 7))
        Set Report1 = Worksheets(1).Buttons.Add(Targeter.Left, Targeter.Top, Width:=2, Height:=0.33)
        With Report1
            .OnAction = "WeeklyReportsP1"
            .Caption = "Weekly Reports P1"
            .Name = "Weekly Reports P1"
        End With
    Case 2:
        Set Targeter = Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(5, 7), Cells(5, 7))
        Set Report1 = Worksheets(1).Buttons.Add(Targeter.Left, Targeter.Top, Width:=2, Height:=0.33)
        With Report2
            .OnAction = "WeeklyReportsP2"
            .Caption = "Weekly Reports P2"
            .Name = "Weekly Reports P2"
        End With
    Case 3:
        Set Targeter = Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(7, 7), Cells(7, 7))
        Set Report1 = Worksheets(1).Buttons.Add(Targeter.Left, Targeter.Top, Width:=2, Height:=0.33)
        With Report3
            .OnAction = "WeeklyReportsP3"
            .Caption = "Weekly Reports P3"
            .Name = "Weekly Reports P3"
        End With
    Case 4:
        Set Targeter = Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(9, 7), Cells(9, 7))
        Set Report1 = Worksheets(1).Buttons.Add(Targeter.Left, Targeter.Top, Width:=2, Height:=0.33)
        With Unique
            .OnAction = "CalculateUnique"
            .Caption = "Calculate Unique"
            .Name = "Calculate Unique"
        End With
    Case 5:
        Set Targeter = Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(11, 7), Cells(11, 7))
        Set Report1 = Worksheets(1).Buttons.Add(Targeter.Left, Targeter.Top, Width:=2, Height:=0.33)
        With NewWork
            .OnAction = "NewWeekWorkSheet"
            .Caption = "Create New Worksheet"
            .Name = "Create New Worksheet"
        End With
End Select
Next i


End Sub
```

The error generates in Case 2 at the line with .OnAction. Which also seems odd to me, because it doesn't throw an error in Case 1... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you step through and skip Case 2 and continue until it goes through with Case 3 does it error there as well?

Comment: Currently it seems you are not creating a Report2 button in case 2, but rather a Report1. When you then call the .OnAction it points to a Report2, that has not been set yet. Same applies to the other cases

Comment: Having a look at your code, it looks like your buttons will be _really_ small too, though I guess that's something you can root out later. I also take issue with  how you declare your targeter-range. Might as well just set it to `Worksheets(1).Cells(3,7)`.

Comment: your answer is given by @tom below. Another thing I did not understand is why you used for loop and case selection. With current structure they are totally useless???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have forgotten to change the "Report1" to Report2, Report3 etc. in every case after copy&pasting from case 1. (:

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of the fantastic feedback! It works now and here's the code:

```
Sub DONOTUSEbuttonMaker()
Dim Report1, Report2, Report3, Unique, NewWork As Button
Dim Targeter As Range

Set Targeter = Worksheets(1).Cells(3, 7)
Set Report1 = Worksheets(1).Buttons.Add(Targeter.Left, Targeter.Top, Width:=144, Height:=24)
With Report1
    .OnAction = "WeeklyReportsP1"
    .Caption = "Weekly Reports P1"
    .Name = "Weekly Reports P1"
End With

Set Targeter = Worksheets(1).Cells(5, 7)
Set Report2 = Worksheets(1).Buttons.Add(Targeter.Left, Targeter.Top, Width:=144, Height:=24)
With Report2
    .OnAction = "WeeklyReportsP2"
    .Caption = "Weekly Reports P2"
    .Name = "Weekly Reports P2"
End With

Set Targeter = Worksheets(1).Cells(7, 7)
Set Report3 = Worksheets(1).Buttons.Add(Targeter.Left, Targeter.Top, Width:=144, Height:=24)
With Report3
    .OnAction = "WeeklyReportsP3"
    .Caption = "Weekly Reports P3"
    .Name = "Weekly Reports P3"
End With

Set Targeter = Worksheets(1).Cells(9, 7)
Set Unique = Worksheets(1).Buttons.Add(Targeter.Left, Targeter.Top, Width:=144, Height:=24)
With Unique
    .OnAction = "CalculateUnique"
    .Caption = "Calculate Unique"
    .Name = "Calculate Unique"
End With

Set Targeter = Worksheets(1).Cells(11, 7)
Set NewWork = Worksheets(1).Buttons.Add(Targeter.Left, Targeter.Top, Width:=144, Height:=24)
With NewWork
    .OnAction = "NewWeekWorkSheet"
    .Caption = "Create New Worksheet"
    .Name = "Create New Worksheet"
End With

End Sub
```

Any recommendations on cleaning it up, would be much appreciated! I'm very new to Object Oriented Programming and would love to get some feedback on better programming practices! Thanks again!